# Sleep in Qt 5.6

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a game using Qt 5.6 and I need to use method `sleep()`.

Are there any Qt modules that include `sleep` function instead of `QThread::sleep()`? Because I don't think that using `QThread` library for the single method is a good practice.

Also, using `QTest::qSleep()` gives me a compiler error - `undefined reference to 'QTest::qSleep(int)'`.

Are there any other possibilities to use method `sleep()` in Qt style?

Comment: I think that you usually use more than one thread so why dont you use that? or you can write some helper function.. as in the "duplicate" comment.. I checked the 5.6 docs there isnt any "core" sleep function..

Comment: You can use c++11 thread library: `this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(n))` look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Comment: There is no place for `sleep()` in a game. Why do you think you need to wait for an arbitrary amount of time?

Comment: Even if it is no place for sleep() in the game it does not change the substance of the question :)

Comment: Why do you think you need to use sleep? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: "to use method sleep() in Qt style” - Qt-style sleep() is not to sleep() :). There’s no place for sleep in the main thread of a UI application, as it blocks everything, i.e. user input. UI painting etc.

Comment: Frank, thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it makes no sense, if one thread could command another thread to sleep,
there is only one single possibility to sleep:
you can only force the current thread to sleep with the static QThread::sleep() method.